# Selenium unable to find class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
mail = driver.find_element_by_name('identifier')
mail.clear()
mail.send_keys('example@gmail.com')
mail_next = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
mail_next.click()

time.sleep(2)

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('102938')
password_next = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
password_next.click()

time.sleep(2)

compose = driver.find_element_by_class_name('T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3')
compose.click()

time.sleep(2)

to = driver.find_element_by_name('to')
to.clear()
to.send_keys('example@gmail.com')

subject = driver.find_element_by_name('subjectbox')
subject.clear()
subject.send_keys('Subject')

body = driver.find_element_by_id('Am Al editable LW-avf tS-tW')
body.clear()
body.send_keys('bro, it works')
```

The error is "Message: Unable to locate element: .T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3"

I even tried Xpath, so it is clear that the class isn't present in the driver

I couldn't find out what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to click the compose button in GMAIL

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Compose')]"))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

compose = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Compose')]")
compose.click()
```

If you want to do it by class, the following code also works.

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']"))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

compose = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")
compose.click()
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to. It's just the practice I use with selenium. Additionally, you could put the click() in a try/except so that if the element is not found for whatever reason, the program does not crash.